# Why does my poppy seed filling have a bitter aftertaste?

Tags: boiling, seeds

I've followed the recipe [here](http://natashaskitchen.com/2014/09/22/how-to-make-poppy-seed-filling/) to make a poppy seed filling. The filling ended up with a somewhat bitter aftertaste, and I am wondering about the following:
At what point in that recipe could something have happened to cause the bitterness?
I tasted the seeds before and they weren't bitter, implying that something happened over the course of preparation. Could it have been something with the simmering (simmering too long, bringing it to a boil, etc.)?

Comment: How old are your poppy seeds? The high oil content could have made the poppy seeds go rancid, and the cooking might have brought out the oils, highlighting that taste.

Comment: Also to note, the website you link to mentions bitterness found in lower quality product. Which I suspect is the same problem with oils going rancid. Could that be a problem?

Comment: That recipe uses unground poppy seeds (could it be that pre-ground was mistakenly used, and over-processed by regrinding it?), they should have less problems with spoilage than pre-ground...